# Runtime CSS fails silently when Flex application is loaded by a non-Flex application

Tags: css, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I have compiled a CSS swf file which includes embedded skins for my Flex application.  In our download product, this CSS works fine.  On the web, a non-Flex container is loading the Flex application, and the CSS fails silently.

When the application is debugged, the following runtime error can be seen in the trace output, but is not raised as an exception.

```
method not implemented mx.core::IFlexDisplayObject/mx.core:IFlexDisplayObject::setActualSize()
   over-binding 0 in GlobalStyle__embed_css__319796825

accessor not implemented mx.core:IFlexDisplayObject::measuredHeight
   over-binding 0 in GlobalStyle__embed_css__319796825

accessor not implemented mx.core:IFlexDisplayObject::measuredWidth
   over-binding 0 in GlobalStyle__embed_css__319796825

method not implemented mx.core::IFlexDisplayObject/mx.core:IFlexDisplayObject::move()
   over-binding 0 in GlobalStyle__embed_css__319796825
```

**Update**

Now that I've determined the actual problem, I've editted the question to be more useful and direct.

Comment: Could you post the contents of the CSS file, so that we can see what kind of statements might be causing these errors?

Comment: I can't post the entire CSS for NDA reasons, but I have included a specific sample of what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The non-Flex application is using content from the library with the same class name as the Flex skins embedded in the CSS swf.  Because Flash looks to the most global swf for class definitions, it is using the classes defined by the non-Flex application.

Because this content does not extend UIMovieClip, it is causing the StyleManager to fail.  Due to potential security errors, Adobe has wrapped most of this process in try-catch blocks to supress expected runtime errors.

Rename the classes used by one application or the other in order to resolve this issue.